# How can i print `n in PowerShell as string?

Tags: powershell, escaping, newline

how can I insert `n in a PowerShell string? I want to display `n but I am not able to escape the newline.

Thanks,

DD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways. Here are two:

With single quotes:

```
'This is `n stuff'
```

Or with double quotes:

```
"This is ``n stuff"
```

Comment: Depending on context, a single back-tick inside double-quotes may work while two will not.  For example:  Write-Host $Thing1, "`n", $Thing2